# Understanding querySelector & querySelectorAll's console output

Tags: javascript, console, selectors-api

**Who/what decides how to write the contents of an `object` to the `console`?**

Sometimes you'll get a collapsable representation of the object literal while other times it simply prints the `DOM` structure.

Given this HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <video src="low.mp4"></video>
  <video src="high.mp4"></video>
  <video src="mega.mp4"></video>
</div>
```

If we hit the `console` (WebKit/Firebug) with:

```
> var firstVideo = document.querySelector('video')
```

And then:

```
> firstVideo
```

It returns:

```
<video src=​"low.mp4">​</video>​
```

While, say we've got another object like:

```
var guitar = { name:'Stratocaster', strings:6 }
```

Asking the console for:

```
> guitar
```

Gives us:

[image: console output]

I've run into the behavior a number of times but typically side-stepped my curiosity by some other means. Now it's sort of a pain so I'm looking into it some more. Is it simply because the object in question *is* a `DOM` element and the inspector is just helping us out?

(I realize my example is a little odd (comparing a `DOM` object and a literal), but it's the simplest/quickest way to illustrate the issue.)

Using some info from a previous question I could get a little more info about each object in question:

`video.constructor` returns:

```
HTMLVideoElementConstructor
```

While: `guitar.constructor` returns:

```
function Object() {
  [native code]
}
```

**Why does it matter?**

Situations like:

```
> firstVideo.parentElement
```

I can't look at this element and inspect its properties as simply when I have to go after each one individually (i.e., `firstVideo.parentElement.offsetHeight`), which is a total bummer.

So, where's the gap in my understanding--what's *actually* going on?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The consoles log differently if the result is an DOM element. They output the source HTML (or XML) of the element instead of listing its properties.
 - `querySelector` returns a DOM element, so the console shows the source of the element.
 - `querySelectorAll` returns an array of DOM elements, which should show an array as normal.

You can always force the output list the properties of an object by using `dir(object)`.

You can check out the [Firebug Command Line API](http://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Command_Line_API).

Comment: Thank you! Of note, Apple's got the WebKit console API documented [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/AppleApplications/Conceptual/Safari_Developer_Guide/DebuggingYourWebsite/DebuggingYourWebsite.html).

Answer (score 2):

When you log a dom node (that is your situation because querySelector returns an element) into the console you get its string representation because it's more clear and it makes you access some standard functionality like highlight the node if you hover the log message or get its location into the document if you click it. If you want to log a dom node like every other object to inspect its properties you can use `console.dir(node)`.

In the other case when you log the constructor of a simple object and the constructor of a dom node the result is the same (in Firebug at least) because you are logging a function and the console prints its name, that is `HTMLVideoElementConstructor` for video elements and `Object` for simple objects.

Comment: Thanks! I understood _what_ I was asking the `console` to print, just not _how_ to coerce it.